# Is there a Non-Retina Macbook Pro 2015?

Tags: macbook-pro

I want to buy a new MacBook Pro and I'm wondering if there's a non-retina MacBook Pro 2015.

I'm asking this because on the compare Mac models page (http://www.apple.com/mac/compare/), there's a Non-Retina MacBook Pro, is it 2015 or all 2015 are always retina?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[No, the non-Retina models are 2012.](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201300)

Comment: But why apple is still selling 2012 macbooks. I mean why there's a non-retina macbook pro on the main compare page?

Comment: @user Because Apple hasn't updated that line of MacBooks since 2012. They're still sold and supported by Apple, hence they're still on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, the non retina has been sold till 2016 and the options included various choices like an ssd that the early configurations didn't have